# why sendmail (ubuntu) + mail function (php) send to SPAM folder (gmail)

Tags: sendmail

This code what i am using to send mail but unfortunately mail goes to spam folder (gmail only). php code is

```
$from = "Test <testFromEmail@gmail.com>"; 
 $headers  = "From: $from \n";
    $headers .= "Cc: $from\n"; 
    $headers .= "X-Sender: $from \n";
    $headers .= 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    $headers .= "X-Priority: 1\n"; // Urgent message!
    $headers .= "Return-Path: $from \n"; // Return path for errors
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

$to      = 'TestToEmail@gmail.com';
$subject = 'subject';
$message = 'content';

if ( mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers) ) {
   echo "The email has been sent!";
   } else {
   echo "The email has failed!";
}
```

Is there any missing function which i need to add or modify to solve this problem